# How to make recursive ManyToManyField relationships that have extra fields symmetrical in Django?

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

```
class Food_Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    related_tags = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False, through='Tag_Relation')

    def __unicode__(self):
     return self.name

class Tag_Relation(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey(Food_Tag, related_name='source_set')
    target = models.ForeignKey(Food_Tag, related_name='target_set')
    is_a = models.BooleanField(default=False); # True if source is a target
    has_a = models.BooleanField(default=False); # True if source has a target
```

I want to be able to get the relations between Food_Tags like:

```
>>> steak = Food_Tag.objects.create(name="steak")
>>> meat = Food_Tag.objects.create(name="meat")
>>> r = Tag_Relation(source=steak, target=meat, is_a=True)
>>> r.save()
>>> steak.related_tags.all()
[<Food_Tag: meat>]
>>> meat.related_tags.all()
[]
```

but related_tags is empty for meat. I realize this has to do with the 'symmetrical=False' argument, but how can I set up the model such that 'meat.related_tags.all()' returns all related Food_Tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships):

> - When defining a many-to-many relationship from a model to
>     itself, using an intermediary model, you *must* use
>     [`symmetrical=False`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) (see
>     [*the model field reference*](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/ref/models/fields/#manytomany-arguments)).

Thus, it is not (yet?) possible to have a symmetrical, recursive many-to-many relationship with extra fields, in Django.  It's a "pick two" sorta deal.

Comment: For information, this is possible since Django 3.0 :
*Specifying symmetrical=True for recursive many-to-many relationships using an intermediary model was allowed.*
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield

Answer (score 2):

I found this approach made by [Charles Leifer](https://charlesleifer.com/blog/self-referencing-many-many-through/) which seems to be a good approach to overcome this Django limitation.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Since you didn't explicitly say that they need to be asymmetrical, the first thing I'll suggest is setting `symmetrical=True`. This will cause the relation to work both ways as you described.</strike> As eternicode pointed out, you can't do this when you're using a `through` model for the M2M relationship. If you can afford to go without the `through` model, you can set `symmetrical=True` to get exactly the behavior you describe.

If they need to remain asymmetrical however, you can add the keyword argument `related_name="sources"` to the `related_tags` field (which you might want to consider renaming to `targets` to make things more clear) and then access the related tags using `meat.sources.all()`.

Answer (score 0):

To create a symmetrical relationship, you have two options:

1) Create two `Tag_Relation` objects - one with `steak` as the source, and another with `steak` as the target:

```
>>> steak = Food_Tag.objects.create(name="steak")
>>> meat = Food_Tag.objects.create(name="meat")
>>> r1 = Tag_Relation(source=steak, target=meat, is_a=True)
>>> r1.save()
>>> r2 = Tag_Relation(source=meat, target=steak, has_a=True)
>>> r2.save()
>>> steak.related_tags.all()
[<Food_Tag: meat>]
>>> meat.related_tags.all()
[<Food_Tag: steak]
```

2) Add another ManyToManyField to the `Food_Tag` model:

```
class Food_Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    related_source_tags = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False, through='Tag_Relation', through_fields=('source', 'target'))
    related_target_tags = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False, through='Tag_Relation', through_fields=('target', 'source'))

class Tag_Relation(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey(Food_Tag, related_name='source_set')
    target = models.ForeignKey(Food_Tag, related_name='target_set')
```

As a note, I'd try to use something more descriptive than `source` and `target` for your through model fields.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution of this problem (after many investigations) was to manually create symmetrical db record on `save()` call. This results in DB data redundancy, of course, because you create 2 records instead of one. In your example, after saving `Tag_Relation(source=source, target=target, ...)` you should save reverse relation `Tag_Relation(source=target, target=source, ...)` like this:

```
class Tag_Relation(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey(Food_Tag, related_name='source_set')
    target = models.ForeignKey(Food_Tag, related_name='target_set')
    is_a = models.BooleanField(default=False);
    has_a = models.BooleanField(default=False);

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('source', 'target')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        # create/update reverse relation using pure DB-level functions
        # we cannot just save() reverse relation because there will be a recursion
        reverse = Tag_Relation.objects.filter(source=self.target, target=self.source)
        if reverse.exists():
            reverse.update(is_a=self.is_a, has_a=self.has_a)
        else:
            Tag_Relation.objects.bulk_create([
                Tag_Relation(source=self.target, target=self.source, is_a=self.is_a, has_a=self.has_a)
            ])
```

The only disadvantage of this implementation is duplicating `Tag_Relation` entry, but except this everything works fine, you can even use Tag_Relation in InlineAdmin.

**UPDATE**
Do not forget to define `delete` method as well which will remove reverse relation.

Comment: Actually, Django implements symmetry in that very way.  It creates another record in the database.