# Django queryset attach or annotate related object field

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

It is needed to attach to queryset results related object field.

Models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Membership',
        blank=True, null=True, symmetrical=False)


class Membership(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(choices=SOME_CHOICES, max_length=50)
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="member_from")
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="member_to")
```

I can do this:

```
>>> User.objects.all().values('name', 'member_from__status')
[{'member_from__status': u'accepted', 'name': 'Ann'}, {'member_from__status': u'thinking', 'name': 'John'}]
```

`'member_from__status'` contains information, that i need. But together with it, i need a model instance also.

What i want is:

```
>>> users_with_status = User.objects.all().do_something('member_from__status')
>>> users_with_status
[<User 1>, <User 2>]

>>> users_with_status[0] # <-- this is an object, so i can access to all its methods
```

Every instance in queryset has a 'member_from__status' field with corresponding value:

```
>>> users_with_status[0].member_from__status
u'accepted'
```

How this could be achieved?

Comment: You can do, `>>> users_with_status[0].member_from.status`

Comment: unfortunately, this will create a DB query at each `users_with_status[n].member_from.status` access

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) and [`F`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)

```
>>> from django.db.models import F
>>> users = User.objects.all().annotate(member_from__status=F('member_from__status'))
>>> users[0].member_from__status
'accepted'
```

Tested with Django versions 1.11 and 2.2

---

### In answer to comments

Here I guess we are rather interested by `member_to__status` than `member_from__status` (we want the user being requested to accept the friendship, not the other way around)

Here's the content of my `membership` table:

```
status   |  from|   to
---------+------+-----
accepted |     1|    2
accepted |     2|    3
 refused |     3|    1
```

Since "[it's not possible to have a symmetrical, recursive `ManyToManyField`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4135643/2116001)" (e.g. user 1 accepted user 2 so user 1 is now in user 2's friend list but user 2 is also in user 1's friends), this is how I would retrieve all actual friends:

```
>>> for user in User.objects.all():
...     friends = user.friends.filter(member_to__status='accepted')
...     print(str(user.id) + ': ' + ','.join([str(friend.id) for friend in friends]))
1: 2
2: 3
3:
```

If you want to have `<User 1>` in `<User 2>`'s friends, I'd suggest to add another `Membership` when the friendship from 1 to 2 has been accepted.

Here we assume that a `Membership` can only be accepted once, so it could be a good idea to add the [unique-together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) option. Nonetheless, if we have several `Membership` with same `from_user`, this is what happens:

```
>>> # <Insert several Membership from one to another User>
>>> Membership.objects.filter(from_user__id=1, to_user__id=2).count()
3
>>> users = User.objects.annotate(member_from__id=F('member_from__id'))
>>> print('User Membership')
... for user in users:
...    print("%4d %10d" % (user.id, user.member_from__id))
User Membership
   1          1
   2          2
   1          3  # User 1 again
   1          4  # User 1 again
   3          None
```

Comment: So the value "accepted" come from the latest `Membership` instance of the `User` ?

Answer (score 4):

Currently i found a solution only using raw query.

Simplified query for `user.friends.all()` is:

```
SELECT "users_user"."id", "users_user"."name", FROM "users_user" INNER JOIN "users_membership" ON ("users_user"."id" = "users_membership"."to_user_id") WHERE "users_membership"."from_user_id" = 10;
```

As we can see, `users_membership` table is already joined. So, i copy this query and just add a `"users_membership"."status"` field.
Then, i create a methon in my model `friends_with_status` and insert new SQL query into `raw` queryset method. My User models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Membership',
        blank=True, null=True, symmetrical=False)


    def friends_with_status(self):
        return User.objects.raw('SELECT "users_membership"."status", "users_user"."id", "users_user"."name", FROM "users_user" INNER JOIN "users_membership" ON ("users_user"."id" = "users_membership"."to_user_id") WHERE "users_membership"."from_user_id" = %s;', [self.pk])
```

Now, i use this:

```
>>> user = User.objects.get(name="John")
>>> friends = user.friends_with_status()
>>> friends[0].status
'accepted'
>>> friends[1].status
'thinking'
```

### P.S.

Of course, this includes all disadvantages of raw query: it is not possible to apply any further queryset methods on it, i.e. this will not work:

```
>>> friends = user.friends_with_status().filter()
>>> friends = user.friends_with_status().exclude()
```

and so on. Also, if i modify model fields, i have to modify the raw query also.

But at least, such approach gives me what i need in one query.

I think, it will be useful to write some annotation method, like `Count` or `Avg`, that will allow to attach fields from joined table.
Something like this:

```
>>> from todo_my_annotations import JoinedField
>>> user = User.objects.get(name="John")
>>> friends = user.friends.annotate(status=JoinedField('member_from__status'))
```

Comment: I'm glad to see I'm not the only person with this issue....   I had thought that the only way to do this was with raw SQL and you confirmed my suspicion.   I wish there was a better way...

Comment: Maybe you could use `.extra(select={"status": my_query})` to not lose the queryset methods?

Comment: I also have this problem. It is surprising that it can't be solved with raw sql and a pity also as I would like to be able to use further chaining. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901376/rewrite-raw-sql-as-django-query