# How to make a recursive ManyToMany relationship symmetrical with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

[I have read the Django Docs regarding `symmetrical=True`.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) I have also read [this question asking the same question for an older version of Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129439/how-to-make-recursive-manytomanyfield-relationships-that-have-extra-fields-symme) but the following code is not working as the Django docs describe.

```py
# people.models
from django.db import models


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("self",
                                     through='Friendship',
                                     through_fields=('personA', 'personB'),
                                     symmetrical=True,
                                     )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Friendship(models.Model):
    personA = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='personA')
    personB = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='personB')
    start = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    end = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return ' and '.join([str(self.personA), str(self.personB)])
```

If `bill` and `ted` are friends, I would expect `bill.friends.all()` to included `ted`, and `ted.friends.all()` to include `bill`. This is not what happens. `bill`'s query includes `ted`, but `ted`'s query does not include bill.

```
>>> from people.models import Person, Friendship
>>> bill = Person(name='bill')
>>> bill.save()
>>> ted = Person(name='ted')
>>> ted.save()
>>> bill_and_ted = Friendship(personA=bill, personB=ted)
>>> bill_and_ted.save()
>>> bill.friends.all()
<QuerySet [<Person: ted>]>
>>> ted.friends.all()
<QuerySet []>
>>> ted.refresh_from_db()
>>> ted.friends.all()
<QuerySet []>
>>> ted = Person.objects.get(name='ted')
>>> ted.friends.all()
<QuerySet []>
```

Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding something?

EDIT: Updated code to show the behavior is the same with `through_fields` set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to add the relationship is `bill.friends.add(ted)`. This will make `bill` friends with `ted` and `ted` friends with `bill`. If you want to set values for the extra fields on the intermediate model, in my case `start` and `end`, use the `through_defaults` argument for `add()`.

```
...
>>> bill.friends.add(ted, through_defaults={'start': datetime.now()}
```

There are cases where you want the relationship between `bill` -> `ted` to have different values on the intermediate model than `ted` -> `bill`. For example, `bill` thinks `ted` is "cool", when they first meet, but `ted` thinks `bill` is "mean". You'll need helper function in that case.

```py
# people.models
from django.db import models


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("self", through='Friendship')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def add_friendship(self, person, impressionA, impressionB, recursive=True):
        self.friends.add(person, through_defaults={'personA_impression': impressionA, 'personB_impression': impressionB)
        if recursive:
            person.add_friendship(self, impressionB, impressionA, False)

class Friendship(models.Model):
    personA = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='a')
    personB = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='b')
    personA_impression = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    personB_impression = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return ' and '.join([str(self.personA), str(self.personB)])
```

Calling `bill.friends.add(ted, through_defaults={"personA_impression": "cool", "personB_impression": "mean"})` results in the following:

```
...
>>> bill_and_ted = Friendship.objects.get(personA=bill)
>>> ted_and_bill = Friendship.objects.get(personA=ted)
>>> bill_and_ted.personA_impression
"cool"  # bill thinks ted is cool
>>> bill_and_ted.personB_impression
"mean"  # ted thinks bill is mean
>>> ted_and_bill.personA_impression
"cool"  # ted thinks bill is cool. This contradicts the bill_and_ted intermediate model
```

Using the `add_friendship` function assigns the proper values to the fields.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields):

> When you have more than one foreign key on an intermediary model to any (or even both) of the models participating in a many-to-many relationship, you must specify `through_fields`. This also applies to [recursive relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#recursive-relationships) when an intermediary model is used and there are more than two foreign keys to the model, or you want to explicitly specify which two Django should use.

Comment: The behavior is the same with `through_fields` set. I've updated my question